# use of ?. syntax in Angular with patchValue

Tags: angular, conditional-operator

I have the following code in my project:

```
this.formGroup.patchValue({
            codAzione: this.stepConfigEvento ? this.stepConfigEvento.pratica.azione : null,
            codRegola: this.stepConfigEvento ? this.stepConfigEvento.pratica.regola : null
        })
```

I thought I could use the ?. syntax to shorten it up a bit, but the compiler complains, is this legal?

```
this.formGroup.patchValue({
            codAzione: this.stepConfigEvento?.pratica.azione,
            codRegola: this.stepConfigEvento?.pratica.regola
        })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the compiler complain with ` this.stepConfigEvento?.pratica.azione ?? null` ?

Comment: yes unfortunately

Comment: Hi @rekotc , their both a different syntax, the first one "this.stepConfigEvento ? this.stepConfigEvento.pratica.azione : null,"  here you mean if  this.stepConfigEvento exist and i the second there's now condition by cocatinationg the  this.stepConfigEvento and the "?"

Comment: Oh, ok... I thought somehow the compiler could figure out that I wanted to update the value or set it to null. I guess I was too optimistic :D

Comment: the "safe operator" (the `.?`) is valid from typescript 3.7. Angular 10 work in typescript 3.9 (Angular 9 can use typescript 3.6 and 3.7), so the answer is yes. But I'm not pretty sure what happens if strict Mode is true

Comment: Hi, please provide full error message.

Comment: if I understand correctly, since I'm using typescript 3.5.3 and Angular 8.2.14 I'm out of luck as this syntax is not supported. The only weird thing is that ?. works when I use it inside an .html like this {{field?.label}}